# Is there a way to include a post multiple times in the same query result?

Tags: wp-query

most people appear to have a problem removing "duplicate posts", I've been trying to retrieve a pre-defined list of posts via 'post__in' and "p" array. The array contains certain post_ids twice, on purpose, like

```
array (164,189,200,164,12,13,164)
```

However, the result set only contains the posts once.

I would, for efficiency reasons, prefer to avoid to create a new loop for all elements in the array. Is there a way to achieve this? I can't seem to get it done.

Thanks!

Comment: `post__id`, like `'post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 )`, work with an arrayy of post IDs. Maybe you add your code here to helps you.

Comment: Hey! Thanks!

That's interesting - I can't find "post__id" in the documentation for wp_query (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters). However, it doesn't appear to work in my case, using post__id as an argument as shown below results in a result set of all posts of the post_type, not just three times 163, while post__in will give me the post 163, but only once

`$new_query = new WP_Query( array (
    'post__id' => array(163,163,163),
    'post_type'      => 'my_post_type'
    ));
`

Comment: Im sorry, `post__id` was a mistake, `post__in` is the right key.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired result by adding this code.

```
<?php 

global $post;
foreach ($p_ids as $p_id) :
    $posts = get_post($p_id);
    setup_postdata( $posts );
    the_title();
endforeach;
```

Comment: "I would, for efficiency reasons, prefer to avoid to create a new loop for all elements in the array."

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I've done this and it works, but if possible I'd prefer a one query solution.

Comment: "Is there a way to include a post multiple times in the same query result?" - Yes. It turns out / this is one of the ways.